# Visual Studio 2015 application running on development server and not running on test server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a standalone VS2015 application run through a batch job.

The xxx.bat job calls the xxx.exe which generates output.

I have tested the complete solution on my local machine and development server which runs completely fine. But, the same code deployed to test server is crashing saying **RptBat.Console stopped working** with **'CLR203r'** error in **System.Configuration.**

The application does not enter any log information for me to troubleshoot.
I tried to update the xxx.cmd.exe.config file but it does not help.

Please advice!

Stack trace is really big about the appsettings file but everything seems to be okay with the file.

```
C:\rptbat>call C:\rptbat\rptbat.cmd.exe -v P
log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Exception while reading ConfigurationSe
ttings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed t
o initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The 'config
uration' start tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 2
6, position 5. (C:\rptbat\rptbat.Cmd.exe.config line 26) ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The 'configuration' start
tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 26, position 5.

at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Skip()
at System.Configuration.XmlUtil.StrictSkipToNextElement(ExceptionAction actio
n)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(XmlUtil
xmlUtil, String parentConfigKey, Boolean inLocation, String locationSubPath, Ov
errideModeSetting overrideMode, Boolean skipInChildApps)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSections(XmlUtil xmlUtil)

at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
eLocal)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(Configurat
ionSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sect
ionName)
at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()
at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_IndentSize()
at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.InitializeSettings()
at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message)
at System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(String message)
at log4net.Util.LogLog.EmitErrorLine(String message)
log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Exception while reading ConfigurationSe
ttings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed t
o initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The 'config
uration' start tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 2
6, position 5. (C:\rptbat\ReportBatcher
.Cmd.exe.config line 26) ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The 'configuration' start
tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 26, position 5.

at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Skip()
at System.Configuration.XmlUtil.StrictSkipToNextElement(ExceptionAction actio
n)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(XmlUtil
xmlUtil, String parentConfigKey, Boolean inLocation, String locationSubPath, Ov
errideModeSetting overrideMode, Boolean skipInChildApps)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSections(XmlUtil xmlUtil)

at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
eLocal)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(Configurat
ionSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetAppSetting(String key)
log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Exception while reading ConfigurationSe
ttings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed t
o initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The 'config
uration' start tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 2
6, position 5. (C:\rptbat\ReportBatcher
.Cmd.exe.config line 26) ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The 'configuration' start
tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 26, position 5.

at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Skip()
at System.Configuration.XmlUtil.StrictSkipToNextElement(ExceptionAction actio
n)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(XmlUtil
xmlUtil, String parentConfigKey, Boolean inLocation, String locationSubPath, Ov
errideModeSetting overrideMode, Boolean skipInChildApps)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSections(XmlUtil xmlUtil)

at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
eLocal)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(Configurat
ionSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetAppSetting(String key)
log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Exception while reading ConfigurationSe
ttings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed t
o initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The 'config
uration' start tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 2
6, position 5. (C:\rptbat\ReportBatcher
.Cmd.exe.config line 26) ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The 'configuration' start
tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 26, position 5.

at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Skip()
at System.Configuration.XmlUtil.StrictSkipToNextElement(ExceptionAction actio
n)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(XmlUtil
xmlUtil, String parentConfigKey, Boolean inLocation, String locationSubPath, Ov
errideModeSetting overrideMode, Boolean skipInChildApps)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSections(XmlUtil xmlUtil)

at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
eLocal)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(Configurat
ionSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetAppSetting(String key)
log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Exception while reading ConfigurationSe
ttings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed t
o initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The 'config
uration' start tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 2
6, position 5. (C:\rptbat\ReportBatcher
.Cmd.exe.config line 26) ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The 'configuration' start
tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 26, position 5.

at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Skip()
at System.Configuration.XmlUtil.StrictSkipToNextElement(ExceptionAction actio
n)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(XmlUtil
xmlUtil, String parentConfigKey, Boolean inLocation, String locationSubPath, Ov
errideModeSetting overrideMode, Boolean skipInChildApps)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSections(XmlUtil xmlUtil)

at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
eLocal)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(Configurat
ionSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetAppSetting(String key)
log4net:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Error while loading XML configuration
System.Xml.XmlException: The 'configuration' start tag on line 2 does not match
the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 26, position 5.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean prese
rveWhitespace)
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
at log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(ILoggerRepository repository, Str
eam configStream)
log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Exception while reading ConfigurationSe
ttings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed t
o initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The 'config
uration' start tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 2
6, position 5. (C:\rptbat\ReportBatcher
.Cmd.exe.config line 26) ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The 'configuration' start
tag on line 2 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 26, position 5.

at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Skip()
at System.Configuration.XmlUtil.StrictSkipToNextElement(ExceptionAction actio
n)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(XmlUtil
xmlUtil, String parentConfigKey, Boolean inLocation, String locationSubPath, Ov
errideModeSetting overrideMode, Boolean skipInChildApps)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSections(XmlUtil xmlUtil)

at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
eLocal)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(Configurat
ionSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetAppSetting(String key)
```

Comment: First, have you ensured that the same .Net framework versions are installed on your `test` environment server that are installed (and used by the application built) on your development (local) machine? Second, if you have it, please include the full stack trace, and any other debug information you can gather from your server that you are experiencing the issue on.

Comment: [some discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a7ed93ad-2923-48c4-9e51-cf0bd6d4e100/net-framework-4-clr20r3-error?forum=netfxsetup) shows, indeed it's .Net problem.. also check your `.config` whatever it named..

Comment: After posting your stacktrace, it does look like you have a malformed config file. Ensure that your config file is not corrupted. Your error says that your `appSettings` does not have matching start/end tags, or that an element preceding that tag is not correct. If possible, include your app.config file in your question.

Comment: From the log, I can see the the exception is from your log4net configuration settings.

Comment: Did you try running with Administration permissions ? Please check the application dependency referred in the config file. It could be anything like permissions/access problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found what the issue was - There was a database connection string in the appsettings file with all the credentials and source information.
The application was not able to read all the special characters declared in the credentials tag. I did not have this issue in Dev server as the credentials were not strong enough as test server. 
Thank you for all the support!